# Error Code 1 with DFTB calculator from ASE package Python

Tags: python, ase

I'm having an issue with the dftb calculator from ASE package.
I'm proving the precision of two methods to optimize some COF structure by stretching the cell isotropically.

So the first function is:

```
def isotropic_cell_relax_2D(atoms, calculator, fmax=0.01):
    """Relaxes the atoms object isotropically in 2D, meaning one scaling factor for cell vectors in x and y is optimized.
        This also means that all angles stay constant.

    Args:
        atoms (_type_): _description_
        calculator (_type_): _description_
        convergence_criterion (float, optional): some sort of convergence criterion. Check what kind is best.
    Returns:
        _type_: _description_
    """
    from ase.optimize import BFGS
    from scipy.optimize import minimize
    
    def energy(scale_factor1):
        atoms1 = atoms.copy()
        # Scale the cell size of the atom object
        atoms1.set_cell(atoms1.get_cell() * scale_factor1, scale_atoms=True)

        # Create an EMT calculator and attach it to the atom object
        atoms1.calc = calculator
        dyn = BFGS(atoms1)
        dyn.run(fmax=fmax)

        # Calculate the energy of the system
        return atoms1.get_potential_energy()
    
    #optimization of the scale factor
    opt = minimize(energy, x0 = 1, method='BFGS', options={'gtol': 1e-5, 'disp': True} )
    scale_factor = opt.x[0]
    #copy of atom object
    atoms2 = atoms.copy()
    
    atoms2.calc = calculator #attach calculator to atoms
    #make the stress/stretch using the scalar factor
    atoms2.set_cell(atoms2.get_cell() * scale_factor, scale_atoms=True)
    
    dyn = BFGS(atoms2)
    dyn.run(fmax=fmax)

    E = atoms2.get_potential_energy()

    results = {'Energy': E}
    
    return results, atoms2, scale_factor
```

there the calculator is attached as

```
calc2 = Dftb(**dftb_GeomOpt)
```

so using this dictionarie

```
dftb_GeomOpt = {'Driver_': 'GeometryOptimization',
            'Driver_Optimizer': 'LBFGS {}',
            'Driver_Convergence_': '',
            'Driver_Convergence_GradElem': 1e-6,
            'Driver_MaxSteps': 3000,
            'Hamiltonian_MaxAngularMomentum_O': 'p',
            'Hamiltonian_MaxAngularMomentum_B': 'p',
            'Hamiltonian_MaxAngularMomentum_C': 'p',
            'Hamiltonian_MaxAngularMomentum_N': 'p',
            'Hamiltonian_MaxAngularMomentum_H': 's',
            'kpts': [1,1,1]
            }
```

I get the error calling that function CalculationFailed: Calculator "dftb" failed with command "/home/jupyter-cgallegos/miniconda3/envs/htc_cofs/bin/dftb+ > dftb.out" failed in /home/jupyter-cgallegos/HTC_COFs/htc_cofs/dummy_recipes with error code 1

Im trying to understand right now the outputs dftb.out and dftb_in.hsd. dftb.out:
[image: dftb.out]

and dftb_in.hsd:
[image: dftb_in.hsd]

Comment: Hey guys, there was a problem on the path file from matsci on the bashrc. So I changed it, but dftb is still looking on that wrong path